# ASP.Net Website Authentication (Active Directory?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, active-directory

I was given a website (coded in ASP.Net; C#, HTML, CSS, and Javascript) to maintain, and the original creators have no longer been in the company for quite some time. I wanted to move the development over to subversion to allow easy rollback/more than one developer to easily work on the files, and in the process of doing so (for an unrelated reason) the process wasn't succcessful.

I removed the version control temporarialy, and manually copied the original folder back to its original location.

Now, however, when people attempt to access the website a dialog appears requesting their username and password, and only users with administrator accounts can log into the website.

I never so much as opened the IIS manager (on a Windows 2003 server), nor are any of the files different to my knowledge, so I don't know why this change would have occured.

Anyone know what is wrong, or a path to troubleshoot?

Comment: Perhaps - **<system.web>
    <authentication mode ="Windows"/>** , in your Web.config

Comment: Is it `intranet application`? what behaviour you actually expecting

Comment: When you copy the folder back to its location the file access permissions might have changed. Do you know what type of access permissions that folder used to have?

Comment: Jasti has it! That was the issue. Changed that, and users can now access the site.